# Inheritance (basic level) what's the best way to ask the user the width and height? (shapes example)

Tags: c++, inheritance, shapes

I made this program to understand inheritance better.

Now that I'm at this basic level it's not really a problem but I can see this coming in the future and so I'm asking what's the best method to ask the user to insert the width and height of a rectangle (in this case).

The code I'm providing includes the simple way, by simply asking the user and inserting the number in a variable, then passing the variable to the setter inside the object (*rect1*).

I think when I will add up more shapes this can become a little confusing, is there a better way I can ask the user to input the number?

**main.cpp:**

```
int main() {
    Rectangle rect1;
    int width, height;

    std::cout << "Insert the width of the rectangle: ";
    std::cin >> width;

    std::cout << "Insert the height of the rectangle: ";
    std::cin >>height;

    rect1.setHeight(height);
    rect1.setWidth(width);

    std::cout << "The area of the rectangle is: " << rect1.getArea() << std::endl;


    std::cout << "Drawing: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < width+1; ++i) {
        std::cout << "-";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < (height+1)/2; ++j) { // divided by 2 to have a better proportion
        std::cout << "|";
        for (int i = 0; i < width+1; ++i) {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "|";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < width+1; ++i) {
        std::cout << "-";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Shape.h:**

```
class Shape {
public:
    int getWidth() const {
        return width;
    }

    void setWidth(int width) {
        Shape::width = width;
    }

    int getHeight() const {
        return height;
    }

    void setHeight(int height) {
        Shape::height = height;
    }

protected:
    int width, height;
};
```

**Rectangle.h:**

```
class Rectangle: public Shape {
public:
    int getArea(){
        return width*height;
    }
};
```

For example I'm thinking about creating another method called "askHeight" that is identical to a setter except it has *cout* and *cin* already inside.

Thanks to everyone! :)

META P.S. 
I already asked here before, without any answer someone said that I should ask on Code Review, and so I did, deleting the old question.
On Code Review they said that I should ask here.
I left the question on Code Review and asked here again to see in which one I can get an answer.
And:
-yes I read all the guidelines
-yes I tried to ask 3 times
-yes I am a beginner, both here and coding

Comment: there is no "best way". What happened when you implemented `askHeight` as you are planning to do? Did you encouter any problems?

Comment: Happy to know that the askHeight method is a good way. Anyway when programs will get more complicated with advanced inheritance and a lot more classes I ask, what's the best method? Implement a "askSomething" method for every class? Create more variables to hold values and ask them in main? Or some other methods that are obscure to me? That's what I mean with "best way". What's the best way to ask the user an input that is going inside a class member?

Comment: I think you didnt get my point, hence I repeat it: There is no best way. A good way is to seperate concerns, ie not to have in and output inside the classes. A common way is to provide overloads for `std::ostream`s `operator<<` and `operator>>` for in and output

Comment: So there actually is a way that is more common to others and there actually is something in my option that is not good, to use input and output inside classes. Is common to overload the iostream operators << and >>... Shall I ask how to do so? If you provide me a better version of doing things... I consider that a better way of mine. I will consider the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you are looking ahead for potential problems. However, your approach to resolving those problems is itself problematic.

You are thinking in terms of "asking the user and [do something to a data structure]". This part of your code is the glue that connects your user interface to your data structures. It should be the *last* part of your design, not the first.
Start by designing your user interface and data structures separately. (**Warning:** don't over-engineer based upon what might happen. If the future is uncertain, don't sacrifice the present. Make it easy to modify your code; don't try to write code that will never need modification.)

Design an ideal user interface with no thought to how you will implement it. After you have an ideal to strive towards, you can figure out how you would implement it. Do not worry about how you will implement the actions triggered by the user; focus on getting those triggers from the user. For example, you might provide a way to input a height and width without concern for how to pass those values to a shape. (If you're writing code or pseudo-code, there would be a gap here to be filled in later.) You might need to compromise the ideal a bit especially when you're starting out. This happens.

Design your data structures based upon the functionality you need. This is in part based upon the user interface you desire, but focus on the functionality rather than on how that functionality is triggered.  Make the structures easy to work with, but don't worry about how they will be accessed from the interface.

**Then**, after you have an interface and data structures sketched out, figure out how you want them to work together. You may find that you want to add new functions to the data structures, which is fine as long as you stick to your design principles. (Maybe each class should have a `static` method to prompt for user input and produce an object. This could shift some interface code into class code, though, so be thoughtful and consistent.) You may find that you want to modify the interface, which is fine as long as the gain outweighs the loss. Sometimes compromises are needed for entities to get along, but each should be allowed to maintain its core integrity.

*Design the interface for the user. Design the structures for the functionality. Design the glue last.*